# How to make solid objects not pass through each other, i.e. how to make a collision?

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I have a tank game and my tanks can rotate, but I can't make a collision between them and game objects

```
void Tank::ActionOnCollision(const sf::FloatRect &collided_object)
{
  const auto kTankGlobalBounds = sprite_.getGlobalBounds();
  const auto kTankOrigin = sprite_.getOrigin();
#pragma region Коллизия справа
  if (kTankGlobalBounds.left < collided_object.left
     && kTankGlobalBounds.left + kTankGlobalBounds.width < collided_object.left + collided_object.width
     && kTankGlobalBounds.top < collided_object.top + collided_object.height
     && kTankGlobalBounds.top + kTankGlobalBounds.height > collided_object.top)
  {
   sprite_.setPosition(collided_object.left - kTankGlobalBounds.width,
                  kTankGlobalBounds.top + kTankOrigin.y);
  }
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Коллизия слева
  else if (kTankGlobalBounds.left > collided_object.left
     && kTankGlobalBounds.left + kTankGlobalBounds.width > collided_object.left + collided_object.width
     && kTankGlobalBounds.top < collided_object.top + collided_object.height
     && kTankGlobalBounds.top + kTankGlobalBounds.height > collided_object.top)
  {
   sprite_.setPosition(collided_object.left + collided_object.width,
                  kTankGlobalBounds.top + kTankOrigin.y);
  }
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Коолизия снизу
  if (kTankGlobalBounds.top < collided_object.top
     && kTankGlobalBounds.top + kTankGlobalBounds.height
        < collided_object.top + collided_object.height
     && kTankGlobalBounds.left < collided_object.left + collided_object.width
     && kTankGlobalBounds.left + kTankGlobalBounds.width > collided_object.left)
  {
   sprite_.setPosition(kTankGlobalBounds.left + kTankOrigin.x,
                  collided_object.top - collided_object.height + kTankOrigin.y);
  }
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Коллизия сверху
  else if (kTankGlobalBounds.top > collided_object.top
     && kTankGlobalBounds.top + kTankGlobalBounds.height
        > collided_object.top + collided_object.height
     && kTankGlobalBounds.left < collided_object.left + collided_object.width
     && kTankGlobalBounds.left + kTankGlobalBounds.width > collided_object.left)
  {
   sprite_.setPosition(kTankGlobalBounds.left + kTankOrigin.x,
                  collided_object.top + kTankGlobalBounds.height + kTankOrigin.y);
  }
#pragma endregion
}
```

Collision from above and below works, but as soon as the tank turns even a little bit, the tank stops colliding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clarified the question

Comment: I think "How collision(intersect) should be resolved" is depend on your APP's specification. Just offset tank position to "opposite" direction? or Some physics-like calculation must be employed? or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a good open source 2D physics library as a reference, and pulling in code you need for specific things like this collision test between two rotated rectangles. Alternately actually integrate and use the library.

[Box2D](https://github.com/erincatto/box2c) is highly recommended by me

Comment: Can you show me how to embed box2d in my SFML project?

Comment: It has been a long time since I did anything this specific. But given that you want to actually do normal game physics stuff like don't walk through things, you should definitely look at integrating some library or another. Btw a huge simplification to your problem is to work with circles.

Comment: Searching Google for 'sf c++ physics library' took me here https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=11112.0 where there is some discussion. The sf forum is probably a good place.

Comment: Actually heres a whole 2d game engine I use to work with, if you want to look for it's collision code specifically for reference. It uses box2d https://github.com/TorqueGameEngines/Torque2D

Comment: Here is the actual cpp file that implements an intersection test between two arbitrary polygons, which is how non-axis-aligned boxes are usually treated (its a polygon with 4 points). https://github.com/TorqueGameEngines/Torque2D/blob/master/engine/source/Box2D/Collision/b2CollidePolygon.cpp

Answer (score 1):

To check if a rectangle collides with another one, you can use the **intersects** function provided by sfml:

```cpp
if(rectangle1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(rectangle2)) //Check the collision
{
    your_code_here
}
```

After checking the collision you can do your own code to collides one with each other. You can also check the collision like this:

```cpp
sf::FloatRect next_pos_x = rectangle1.getGlobalBounds();
next_pos_x.left += horizontal_velocity; //Put your own horizontal velocity/speed.

sf::FloatRect next_pos_y = rectangle1.getGlobalBounds();
next_pos_y.top += vertical_velocity; //Put your own vertical velocity/speed.

sf::FloatRect next_pos = rectangle1.getGlobalBounds();
next_pos.left = next_pos_x.left;
next_pos.top = next_pos_y.top;

if(next_pos_x.intersects(rectangle2.getGlobalBounds())
{
    //Colliding in the X direction.
    //Stop moving in the X direction here.
}
else if(next_pos_y.intersects(rectangle2.getGlobalBounds())
{
    //Colliding in the Y direction.
    //Stop moving in the Y direction here.
}
else if(next_pos.intersects(rectangle2.getGlobalBounds())
{
    //Colliding in both directions.
    //Stop moving in both directions here.
}
```

The code stop moving the rectangle when it hits the second rectangle. If the rectangle checks he's colliding the second rectangle in the X direction, he will stop moving in the X direction, and the same with the Y direction.
I hope this works!

Comment: This specifically does not handle a rotated rectangle. Note its called 'global bounds' meaning its a world aligned bounding box and therefore not rotated.

Comment: For that you can use the SAT collision system...

Answer (score 0):

For 2 rectangles, check below for each edge(there are 8 edges).

Consider splitting the world into two areas by a straight line on which the edge lies.
Here, the rectangle to which the edge belongs is completely contained in the one area.
Check if  the another rectangle is completely contained in the another area.
If so, 2 rectangles do not intersect (not collide).

If, for all 8 checks, straight lines splitted another rectangle, it indicates the 2 rectangles intersect( or one include another whole).

---

If you know "moving speed of tanks is enoughly slow, so, intersect should be always shallow", "vertex vs edge" check may be enough.

What you do is check the intersection of two line segments. One line segment is "center to one vertex", and another is one edge of another rectangle.
When you find crossing, you may be able to use the some information { position of the crossing point, normal of the edge, etc } to your following collision solving process.

Comment: And if they intersect, what should I do?

Comment: Since I think the problem of this question is "how to check collision between 2 rectangles" only, I don't know what you want to do after you find they intersect.

Comment: i want the solid objects not to pass through each other

Comment: But {what is good way, what is not acceptable, etc} for your APP is all depend on you.
e.g. Panalty-Force method will be one of the easy way but it can't solve intersection at a moment. If a bit of intersecting state is acceptable, such way may be used.
Otherwise (if "no intersections existing" must always be strictly maintained), you must employ some other way.

Comment: Also... This my answer covers very "deep" intersection. (e.g. the state one including another whole).
But if you can assume "such deep intersection can not be occurred", other collision detection method may be conceivable, and such method may be able to provide some useful information directly for the "solid object" process. (e.g. contact point, normal vector, relative velocity, etc) .